# Bootable Linux USB stick for micro-usb only Windows machine?

Tags: windows, usb, bootable-media

Is there a way to use a bootable usb-stick for a Windows 64bit device which has only a micro-usb? For example the Lenovo Yoga Book.

Comment: As far as I know microUSB is the same as regular USB, only the form factor differs. That means you only need a simple cable to convert between them. A quick google search shows that these are not expensive.

Comment: @Hennes, NO. microUSB port has extra ID pin as compared to regular USB-A port, which allows to change the port role from device to host. In theory. Practice can differ.

Comment: Ah, I know they have several versions of micro USB (guest and host|guest, but I thought that was also used a different connector. It will be educational to watch this question for its answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Formally**, the microUSB connector comes in four incarnations: cable uA, cable uB, receptacle uB, and receptacle uAB. These connectors have one extra ID pin.

If a device has only one microUSB connector, it should be able to change its functionality from device to host, formerly called "OTG", nowadays it is Dual-Role Port. In theory such device must have the uAB receptacle, meaning that it can fit to both uA (squared) and uB (runded) cable connectors.

If the cable is "rounded" uB type, it has the ID pin floating, and the port assumes a role of USB device (Media player usually), and will take the USB VBUS power for charging itself.

If the cable is uA type (square shaped), it has the ID pin grounded. The device must switch its role to host mode, and instead of consuming VBUS, it must supply it to downstream devices as pen drives, hubs, and keyboards.

The Lenovo Yoga Book, from pictures, has the micro-B receptacle. This means that officially it was not designed for users to be a host, since formally the uA cable will not fit.

However, **informally** the industry has invented a trick called "host adapter cable"[image: host adapter cable]".

This is a piece of short cable with uB connector on one end, and Type-A receptacle on the other. However, against USB OTG specifications, the ID pin in this cable is grounded as in uA connector. So, by plugging this adapter cable into Yoga, the ID pin will be grounded, and a OTG compliant device should be able to become a host and recognize and connect to USB flash derive. This functionality depends on manufacturer's ideas and software/firmware of the tablet. It is very likely that Yoga can do this.

Now, the ability to boot from USB flash is again up to the manufacturer, how they design the BIOS/UEFI firmware, and what options do they provide to end users. There could be no options, to prevent sophisticated users to install different OS and screw up their secure internal partitions, so you are here on your own.